# Laravel Helper Set Class Active Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-helper

I have a helper function.

```
function setActive($path, $active = 'active')
{
    return call_user_func_array('Request::is', (array)$path) ? $active : '';
}
```

When I go to the site: `http://example.net/posts?group=active`, my function is not working and returns an empty string ("").

I use this in my Blade:

```
class="{{ setActive(['posts?group=active'] }}"
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this for navigation? You don't need a helper function to achieve that. In your blade, you can just do...

```php
@if(request()->is() === 'posts')
```

OR

```
{{ request()->is('posts') ? 'active' : '' }}
```